# Dagger 2 Named Set Injection

Tags: dagger-2

I have a injection point:

```
public class Receiver {
  private final Set<Sender> senders;

  @Inject
  public Receiver(@Named("Test") Set<Sender> senders){
     this.senders = senders;
  }
}
```

Moreover I have this module providing the dependency:

```
@Module
public class MyModule {
  @Provides(type = Provides.Type.SET)
  @Singleton
  @Named("Test")
  public Sender provideSender(){
     return new SpecificSender();
  }
}
```

But dagger 2 APT cannot create the appropriate classes. I get this exception from the APT:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at dagger.internal.codegen.KeyVariableNamer.apply(KeyVariableNamer.java:44)
```

Does anyone have the same issue? Is there a good workaround?

If I drop the Named annotation it does work. 
I'm using Dagger 2.0

Thank you

Comment: If I use a Qualifier Annotation the mechanism works. But still, I think it should also work with @Named annotation

Comment: Based on a first glance in the Dagger2 compiler code, this seems to be an edge-case and currently a bug, it even has a `TODO:` comment next to it.

Comment: You might want to [open an issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues) for this.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed internally, but is not yet synced to github.

Comment: This just happened to me on Dagger 2.0.2. Any news on when this fix will be released ?

Comment: @nicopico It happened to me, too. I have filled an issue, here's the link if you want to keep an eye on it: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/343

Comment: Dagger 2.1 has been released BTW; have you checked if it's been fixed in that version?